# Read times of really small files on Linux with ext4

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, disk, ext4

I'm working on comparing the performance of ext4 and NTFS on different file operations. As part of the same, I'm benchmarking reads on really small files (a few bytes) using C. These are of special interest since such small files are stored within the MFT on Windows but on ext4 would have their own disk block. So I should be able to observe a significant difference between read times of such files on NTFS against ext4. The tests are on a set of 100 files 4 bytes each. I measure the time `read` takes on each file.

The plots for read times, however, show patterns that I'm not able to explain. Here's 4 graphs:

[image]

[image]

First graph was generated by running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` before reading each file, second by `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, third by `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and fourth without freeing any cache. For the second and third cases, why do the times go up and down? Shouldn't the times be within the same range throughput?

My first approximation was that since these files are really small, a lot of them get stored in one block and thus multiple files get read in a single block read. Although I'm definitely not sure if this is right. Is it possible that some sort of prefetching of an entire file is going on (although I'd imagine this would not be a good thing to do)? I also thought of checking the actual disk blocks of these files using `debugfs` but I'm not sure if logical block numbers would correspond to the actual disk blocks.